# Any different idea or suggestions on how to Measure distance between wifi access point and my android device?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager

I am developing an android app for my device as part of my college project. I want to measure the distance between WIFI access point and my device using this app. Can I get any suggestion from you guys on this,regarding how to make it possible, keeping in mind about the information which I have discovered below.

Information which I discovered:-

1). The routers or WIFI access point do not have GPS capabilities. Hence, I assume, finding the distance via location is not possible.

2). It is possible to access a database of access points, but I have to request the proprietors  commercially, which again is less practical.

3). I can use triangulation method but as you know its not feasible.

4). I also do not want to do Wifi Fingerprint, which is to measure RSSI signal strength on different location and calculate distance based on that.

Is there anyway out or anything I could do, to find distance between my device and the WIFI access point?? Any new idea as of now ?? Since on the Q&A forums, I discovered above Informations which were not discussed lately.

Comment: How close are you supposed to be able to get to a correct calculation? Without specific GPS points you have a TON of variables to take into consideration. You can likely figure out a way to get within a fairly wide range but any pinpoint accuracy is going to be very difficult.

Comment: @zgc7009 

You are exactly right, it's very hard to expect pinpoint accuracy. So its fine for me to estimate an approximate distance, Can you please point me out the materials/resources or suggest me the other variables(or parameters) which I can taken into consideration to develop an app as such .

Comment: I am going to keep thinking about this one, but without any GPS points and trying  to avoid signal strength I can't even really think of a solid place to start.

Comment: @zgc7009

Lolzz!!.. Back to topic, For me, the concern with RSSI fingerprinting method is that, maybe I can fingerprint the distance to an access point considering its strength only inside my building, office or even university. But if a user downloads the app and uses it in any other location, then this method wont be helping much I guess, as the user wont be doing any fingerprinting stuff or nor can I do it for every location. Please correct me if I am wrong.